# jQuery: change text colour at timed intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I was hoping someone could help me out with a jQuery question.  I have a site where I want blocks of text to change colour within defined time intervals when the page loads.  As an example, in the following code;

```
<div id="fade">


<div class="fade1">text block 1</div>
<div class="fade2">text block 2</div>
<div class="fade3">text block 3</div>

</div>
```

I would like .fade1 to change from color: #000, font-weight: normal; to color: #F00, font-weight: bold for five seconds then return to normal; followed by .fade2 and then .fade3 etc.  I want these effects to happen on page load and not triggered by mouse click or hover.

I’m fairly new to this type of programming and have tried to play around with the jQuery.Color() and .animate() methods but I can’t seem to achieve the effect I want.
Any help much appreciated – thank you.

**This is code I've used since first writing this post:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fade1">Text Block 1</div>
<div id="fade2">Text Block 2</div>
<div id="fade3">Text Block 3</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var index = 0;
setInterval(highlightText, 3000);

function highlightText() {
      index = (index % 3) + 1;
      $('#fade' + index).css('color', '#e7008a').css('font-size', '110%');
      setTimeout(function() {
             $('#fade' + index).css('color', '#000').css('font-size', '100%');
      }, 2900);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd probably just use a normal JavaScript `setTimeout`.

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? A complete sample of the javascript/css/html would help us give you a better answer quicker.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses.  I'll try the setTimeout method.  As I couldn't get any of my earlier attempts to produce the desired results I didn't keep them, so I have no relevant samples to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ready function of your document, you can read more about that [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready).

Use the setTimeout function inside the ready function. You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: I've added some code to my original post that includes the setTimeout function.  It seems to work but I've noticed that on occasion something goes wrong and one of the blocks of text doesn't return to normal before the next one changes.  Can anyone shed any light on way that might be?